# Applying multiple Spring profiles to a single Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, spring-profiles

I have 4 possible Spring profiles for my application

- TEST (This is for Unit/Integration testing)
- QA
- STAGE
- PRODUCTION

The last 3 in the above list are actutal environments in which this application will run.

Here's the overview of my configuration class called AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"org.mycompany.services","org.mycompany.domain", "org.mycompany.utils"})
public class AppContext {

}
```

Here's my question:
I want the AppContext's configuration to be applied for QA, STAGE and PRODUCTION profiles only (But not for TEST profile). What's the best way to do that?

The reason for this is that the above config class scans & picks classes from org.mycompany.services. But I do not want this package to be picked up for TEST profile as I'm intending to mock the classes in this package using Mockito.

Another possible question is if I need to rethink the way I'm approaching Unit/Integration testing so that I can simplify mocking of classes in org.mycompany.service package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation on the configuration class.

To enable the class for any profile except `TEST`, just use it like `@Profile("!TEST")`.

Or you can explicitly specify the profiles like so: `@Profile({ "QA", "STAGE", "PRODUCTION" })`

Comment: How to specify OR/AND condition with @profile annotation

Comment: @c.sankhala Based on the documentation the Profile string can contain a single profile name or an expression e.g. `@Profile({"QA | PRODUCTION"})`. Here's the [docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of(java.lang.String...)).